# Confusion about Pandas datetime formatting

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, export-to-csv

I am getting data from a tool and exporting it to csv on my local machine. I am describing my problem as follows with an example. On the tool for the Date_time column, it is `9/22/2019 10:55 AM`. On the csv file for some reason it became `43730.46328` which is float. Then when I converted it to datetime using pandas  `to_datetime`, it became `1970-01-01 00:00:00.000043730`. I don't understand where did it go wrong. I did not quite understand how the original datetime became a flaot. Is there any way to save the original datetime format when it is exported to csv?

Comment: In the phrase “tool for the Date_time column” what do you mean by “tool”?

Comment: The "tool" is a software on top of high volume manufacturing data. I can check some dashboards for trend charts, tables etc. on top of the tool and do some statistics as well. Many big manufacturers (Samsung, Apple, Intel etc. you name it) have such their own tool either made by their own IT or other third party.

Comment: Alright, can you share your code and some data? See: [mvce].

Comment: Oops I meant [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

You can use `xlrd` to convert `43730.46328` to datetime.

```
import xlrd
d = xlrd.xldate_as_datetime(43730.46328, datemode=0)
```

result:

```
datetime.datetime(2019, 9, 22, 11, 7, 7, 392000)
```

Comment: I saw that https://stackoverflow.com/users/6789321/accdias added some comments, then deleted and downed the question, not clear to me what he did not understand. 
 Anyway ...